# How do I find the arc length of the curve $y = (x+4)^{3/2}$, where x is between $-4$ and $9$?

Tags: calculus

How do I find the arc length of the curve $y = (x+4)^{3/2}$, where x is between $-4$ and $9$?

I'm stuck at this part of the problem. Using the arc-length formula, I get this integral. But i'm not sure how to change the bounds b/c there isn't two points giving. [Here is my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v31B.jpg)

Comment: Please typeset your question using MathJax. It will greatly increase the chance someone will give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify before to substitute u:
$$\sqrt {1+\dfrac 9 4 (x+4)}=\sqrt {10+\dfrac {9x}4}=\dfrac 12 \sqrt {40+ {9x}}$$
If you substitute : 
$$u=40+9x \implies du=9dx$$ 
$$\text { for }  x=-4 \implies u=4$$
$$\text { for }  x=9 \implies u=121$$
The integral becomes:
$$I=\int_{-4}^9\sqrt {1+\dfrac 9 4 (x+4)}dx=\frac 1 {18} \int_{4}^{121}\sqrt u du$$

Comment: thank you, for the clarity!

Comment: You're welcome @ttsega

Answer (score 0):

The new limits should be $1$ and $121/4$.